# Where to find all possibilities to address_components types?

Tags: google-places-api

I need to deal with all that comes from Google Places API and save in a MySQL database.

With that purpose, I need to know all address components types because they will be column in my address table, but after look at documentation and tried to google it, I didn't find a thing.

Is there this information somewhere?

In Documentation [example](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) there are those types:

- floor
- street_number
- route
- locality
- political
- administrative_area_level_2
- administrative_area_level_1
- country
- postal_code

But when I request the API with other address, those types change. Example:

- postal_code
- route
- political
- sublocality
- sublocality_level_1
- administrative_area_level_2
- administrative_area_level_1
- country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, it was at intro, not in Google Place Search or Google Place Detail section:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types

Comment: Why they do not have building number/name there? It is weird

Comment: I was searching for this from quite some time. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this was moved again:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#Types